# Generate an SSL certificate for an intranet server in IIS6 using AD issuer server

Tags: iis-6, ssl-certificate

We have our Windows 2003 server configured as a Certificate Authority for our intranet. The CA itself is certified as, say, mail.externaldomain.com.

We would like to generate further, intranet, certificates from this for individual web applications.

We do not want to self-sign, this is for pre-production testing and are looking to mirror the target deployment as closely as possible.

We have tried this and can't get the certificate to provide either Server or Web server identity. It only provides EFS support.

This means the web browser doesn't accept it.

How can we do this? We are using IIS6 on Windows 2003 Small Business Server.

Comment: What type of CA is it?  Stanalone/Enterprise?

Comment: Thanks Zoredache. It's a Standalone, it's Small Business Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

We were going wrong by putting the wrong name as the name of the certificate (bit unclear, but this is essentially the web address that is being certificated).